# Is it possible clear periodically output when executing while or for in Jupyter python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter notebook of python program to monitoring current status at every second by using `print()`. 
The problem is the program has lack due to a lot of printed lines. So I want to clear the printed lines periodically (e.g., at every minute).

Example code is here.

```
for i in range(100000):
    print(i)
```

The result is as follows.
[image]

My desired output is as follows (period is 10).

[image]

============ The printed result is clear =============

[image]

Is there any python code or jupyter command for this issue?

Comment: You can try the curses package (I don't know what it would do with jupyter) or pick a GUI (tkinter usually comes with python distributions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use IPython.display.clear_output to clear the output of a cell in Jupyter:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
for i in range(100000):
    if i%10 == 0:
        clear_output(wait = True)
    print(i)
```